# GitHub does not allow secrets to be passed down to reusable workflow

Tags: yaml, devops, github-actions

I am trying to pass secrets to reusable workflow as shown here:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows#passing-inputs-and-secrets-to-a-reusable-workflow

But the pipeline fails, stating that:

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/test.workflow-test.yml (Line: 17, Col: 9): Unexpected value 'secrets'
```

My .github/actions/test/action.yml looks like that:

```
name: Reusable workflow example

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      username:
        required: true
        type: string
    secrets:
      token:
        required: true

jobs:
  example_job:
    name: show
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: show data
        runs: echo ${{ secrets.token }}
```

And I'm calling it accordingly:

```
name: Call a reusable workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "feature/workflow-test"

jobs:
  my-test-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: ./.github/actions/test
        with:
          username: John
        secrets:
          token: secret Token
```

What I am missing here? It is almost identical to the code samples within GitHub's documentation.

Comment: Per https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions a step doesn't have a secrets key.

Comment: Maybe the [new (May 2022) keyword `secrets: inherit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72103477/6309) could help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues that I can see with your example.

The path to reusable workflow needs to be `.github/workflows`. Currently subdirs are not supported.

Also, the way you call reusable workflow is not according to docs.

Here's an example that should work:

```
name: Call a reusable workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  reusable-job:
    uses: <owner>/<repo>/.github/workflows/<reusable workflow>@master
    with:
      username: john
    secrets:
      token: test
```

And following reusable workflow:

```
name: Reusable workflow

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      username:
        required: true
        type: string
    secrets:
      token:
        required: true

jobs:
  show:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      - name: Show data
        run: |
          echo ${{ inputs.username }}
          echo ${{ secrets.token}}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the case where I get the same error as OP when trying to pass an actual `${{ secrets.FOO }}` via `with` to the reusable workflow.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic any chance by now you, or anybody else, have found the solution to such problem?