# How to use reusable GitHub workflows and keep secrets in a single place?

Tags: github-actions

While reusable GitHub workflows do help with maintenance of GitHub Actions in general, reducing a lot of copy/paste from one repository to another, they still seem to have one big issue: dealing with secrets.

When implementing an action like "post to Slack", or "post to matrix/IRC", you will need some secrets for the bot account, and if you want to reuse this action in 50 repositories you can imagine while managing secrets in each repository does not scale.

I am looking for a solution to this problem that does not involve deploying secrets to all repositories using an action, some way to centralize them.

Keep in mind that reusable workflows work across organizations and I already have some of them shared across 4+ organizations. So configuring organization level secrets is not a solution either, also for other reasons: they can easily be exposed because they are available to any workflow (as opposed to environment based ones).

Comment: I think reusable workflow is meant as being reusable by anyone, and if secrets as part of the repository can be used by anyone then it would be a huge security issue.

Answer (score 17):

Check if the new (May 2022) keyword **`secrets: inherit`** can help:

> ### [GitHub Actions: Simplify using secrets with reusable workflows](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-05-03-github-actions-simplify-using-secrets-with-reusable-workflows/)
>
> GitHub Actions simplifies using secrets with reusable workflows with the `secrets: inherit` keyword.
>
> Previously when passing secrets to a reusable workflow, you had to pass each secret as a separate argument.
>
> Now you can simply pass the **`secrets: inherit`** to the reusable workflow and the secrets will be inherited from the calling workflow.

Learn more about [reusable workflows in GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-inputs-and-secrets-in-a-reusable-workflow) and [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].uses`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsuses).

> In the reusable workflow, reference the input or secret that you defined in the on key in the previous step.
>
> If the secrets are inherited using `secrets: inherit`, you can reference them even if they are not defined in the on key.
>
> ```yaml
> jobs:
>  reusable_workflow_job:
>    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
>    environment: production
>    steps:
>      - uses: ./.github/workflows/my-action
>        with:
>          username: ${{ inputs.username }}
>          token: ${{ secrets.envPAT }}
> ```
>
> In the example above, `envPAT` is an environment secret that's been added to the production environment. This environment is therefore referenced within the job.
>
> Note: Environment secrets are encrypted strings that are stored in an environment that you've defined for a repository.
> Environment secrets are only available to workflow jobs that reference the appropriate environment.
> For more information, see "[Using environments for deployment.](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#environment-secrets)"

Again, see [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].uses`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsuses) for additional examples.

---

As noted by [wkhatch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168843/wkhatch) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71524542/how-to-use-reusable-github-workflows-and-keep-secrets-in-a-single-place/72103477#comment136630988_72103477):

> I don't believe this syntax is correct for using a reusable workflow, but is **correct for using reusable actions**.
> You cannot call a reusable workflow as a step, but you can with an action.

Comment: Hi @VonC, would you have any insights about using a secret coming not from the caller repository, but from the repository where the reusable workflow leaves? Having to go though organization secrets does not offer much flexibility.

Comment: @FabienP I do not have insights in that: it would be a good question on its own.

Comment: More information about uses is also in docs https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsuses

Comment: @BartłomiejJakubKwiatek Thank you for the link. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I don't believe this syntax is correct for using a reusable workflow, but is correct for using reusable actions. You cannot call a reusable workflow as a step, but you can with an action. Just clarifying here, as I know a guy who got this confused once... ;-)

Comment: @wkhatch Good point, thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 6):

This exact scenario is addressed in the [GitHub roadmap](https://github.com/orgs/github/projects/4247/views/11?filterQuery=label%3Aactions%20status%3A%22Q1%202023%20%E2%80%93%20Jan-Mar%22%2C%22Q2%202023%20%E2%80%93%20Apr-Jun%22%2C%22Q3%202023%20%E2%80%93%20Jul-Sep%22%2C%22Q4%202023%20%E2%80%93%20Oct-Dec%22%2CFuture%20secrets) issue [*GitHub Actions secrets improvements for Reusable workflows*](https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/636):

> With this current improvement, teams managing reusable workflows can refer to the secrets from the called (source) repos. These secrets are available only in the reusable workflow run context within in the caller (target) repos.

Unfortunately, as of March 2024, the issue is scheduled for "Future"; there are columns up to Q4 2024.

Answer (score 1):

Organization secrets can help with this problem, but it's not an ideal solution for all use cases. Your situation is similar to a situation I had with implementing SAST. Rather than having each team setup the job manually and incorrectly set failure levels or forget to output to SARIF and upload, I just created a reusable job. The challenge is the API credentials weren't available from the called workflow repository secrets. I can work around this with org secrets. I have other use cases, where it's much more difficult to use an org secret and still enforce good behavior.