# Using secrets context in with context of a reusable workflow

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have created a reusable workflow that is actually a wrapper around the official docker build-push [action](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action) .

I want to pass build-time secrets as follows

```
jobs:
  test-secrets-passing:
    uses: MyOrg/MyRepo/.github/workflows/myworkflow.yaml@main
    with:
      image_name: some-name
      image_tag: some-tag
      build_args: |
        MY_VAR=${{ vars.MY_VAR }}
      build_secrets: |
        MY_SECRET=${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}
```

This fails with:

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/myworkflow.yaml (Line: 19, Col: 22): Unrecognized named-value: 'secrets'. Located at position 1 within expression: secrets.MY_SECRET
```

Isn't the `secrets` context supported from within `with` context of reusable workflows?

Comment: Use the [`secrets` keyword](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#passing-inputs-and-secrets-to-a-reusable-workflow) to pass secrets to a reusable workflow.

Comment: yes but I want to explicitly pass some named secrets, why am I getting this error?

Comment: Because you're using `with`, and not `secrets`?

Comment: Why does it seem to work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72103477/2409793)?

Comment: That's a call to an action; you're making a call to a reusable workflow.