# Reuse secret from reusable workflow repository in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

In the context of our project, we need to use the secret in the repository containing the reusable workflow and not the caller as we don't share it with the caller (our clients).

The use case looks like:

- Repo A: the client repository
- Repo B: the reusable workflow that contains `secrets.TOKEN`

The caller workflow in Repo A, calls the reusable workflow in Repo B. This workflow can't access the `secrets.TOKEN` set in Repo B.

Any advice for this use case?

Comment: That's not how the security model works. Secrets have to come _from_ the calling workflow, and therefore from its repository (or inherited via organization). See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions.

Comment: If your repos are in an organization, you can leverage the organization secrets and reuse them in both repos.

Comment: @Fares If we set a organization secret, all the callers can gave access to this token.

Comment: The clients might reuse it for purposes other than the reusable workflow designed by the DevOps team.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use reusable GitHub workflows and keep secrets in a single place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71524542/how-to-use-reusable-github-workflows-and-keep-secrets-in-a-single-place)

Answer (score 1):

This exact scenario is on the [GitHub roadmap](https://github.com/orgs/github/projects/4247): [*GitHub Actions secrets improvements for Reusable workflows*](https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/636)

> - The platform team can create a reusable workflow (e.g., `deploy.yml`) in a repository managed by them and also define secrets referred to in the workflow.
> - When a developer team uses the reusable workflow, they don't have to worry about the secrets used in the reusable workflow. Those secrets will not be accessible outside the context of the reusable workflow run.

As of today (March 2024), this is scheduled for "Future", i.e., not before Q1 2025. The alternative today, as pointed out in answers and comments, are organization-level secrets.

Comment: If we set a organization secret, all the caller can gave access to this token.
The clients might reuse it for purposes other than the reusable workflow designed by the DevOps team

Comment: More over, TOKEN will not be set in the context of the run  if not set on the caller env variables even as organization secrets. 

env: 
  TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}

Comment: @hb.Sara Yes, your exact use case isn't currently supported.

Answer (score -1):

You can [add the secret](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/managing-codespaces-for-your-organization/managing-development-environment-secrets-for-your-repository-or-organization#adding-secrets-for-an-organization) to your organization instead of to the repository. Then you can choose which repos have access to the secret.